# Azure Virtual Machine measure Internet Speed

Tags: azure

I am using a windows Virtual Machine(VM) on Azure, I would like to measure the internet speed. As it seems really laggy.

SO I ran the speed test on the VM from *ookla* and it gave  me I believe a  ridiculous number such as 1000 mbps for download and about 250 for upload.

1. Is this the right way to test what I looking for, what am I missing here ?  As simple GDrive / Dropbox sync takes forever on this VM.
2. Just like configuring the virtual machine by choosing the Disk, CPU, RAM etc.. can I choose what internet speed for the machine ?I tired looking into this and seems like it is machine series(B,D,...) dependent. If this is indeed the case, can someone direct me to a simple page or tell me  what can I expect in terms of internet speeds on each series. As this is one of the important considerations for our application.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a trace route, the internet speed might be good even though there is an issue connection to an endpoint.

You can use `tracert` command or `NMAP` for a richer feel.

NMAP Download- http://nmap.org/download.html